# Error in my stored-procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

i have an error in my stored-procedure. I use MySql DB

```
SET @counter = 1;
SET @last = 0;
UPDATE Customer SET ordre = (IF(@last = customer_id,@counter + 1,@counter = 1)),
                 @last = customer_id
```

**My Error**

> Script line: 3    You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@last = customer_id ORDER BY
>   customer_id' at line 2

Comment: what version mysql your using ?

Comment: Ah, I was going to suggest adding "  `   " around `table` , but it's called Customer. check :)

Comment: This point: `@counter := 1` inside the `IF` gives the error I think.

Comment: "order" is a reserved word - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: i edit is name is Ordre not order sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set variables in SET clause of UPDATE statement. '@last = customer_id' causes the error.

From the reference -

UPDATE syntax - '...SET col_name1=expr1 [, col_name2=expr2 ...]'

The SET clause indicates which columns to modify and the values they should be given.

Comment: so is impossible to do why i want .?

Comment: In this way - no. What actually are you going to do?